# Why the endsWith function not working in java?

Tags: java, string

I was writing a program on java on the topic that,

```
Write a program to input a sentence which ends only with ! or ? mark. Each word in the
sentence is separated by single blank space. Covert the sentence into lower case and
replace vowels in each word by two characters ahead in ASCII table and consonants by the
next character (i.e. a follows z). Print message for invalid input.
Example Input- computer is fun? output- dqnqwugs kt gwo.
```

Whenever i am trying to give a correct input, the program tells me that it doesn't end with ? or! sign. I cant understand what shall I do. cane anybody help me?

My Program:

```
package class11;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ascii 
{
    boolean check(String a, String b)
    {
        return a.endsWith(b);
    }
    String toascii(String s)
    {
        String ans="";
        if (check(s,"!")==true ||check(s,"?")==true )
        {
            System.out.println("Ends with ? or !");
            s.trim().toLowerCase();
            String test = s;
            //String lw = test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
            //if(lw=="?"||lw=="!")
            {
                s.trim().toLowerCase();
                int l=s.length();
                for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
                {
                    if(s.charAt(i)=='a'||s.charAt(i)=='e'||s.charAt(i)=='i'||s.charAt(i)=='o'||s.charAt(i)=='u')
                    {
                        char k=(char)(2+(int)(s.charAt(i)));
                        ans=ans+k;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(s.charAt(i)==' ')
                        {
                            ans= ans+' ';
                            i++;
                        }
                        if(s.charAt(i)=='z')
                        {
                            ans= ans+'a';
                            i++;
                        }
                        char k=(char)(1+(int)(s.charAt(i)));
                        ans=ans+k;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not ends with ? or!");
            ans="not eligible";
        }
        return ans;
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Ascii ob=new Ascii();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a sentance:");
        String a=sc.next();
        System.out.println(ob.toascii(a));
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

This is what I am trying to do. But in other programs, this works absolutely fine. I am totally messed up with this.
I am trying to give a correct input, but it shows:

```
Enter a sentance:computer is fun ?
Not ends with ? or!
not eligible

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It would be great if anybody helps me and suggest me a better replacement.

Comment: Hint: either step through this in a debugger, or add some logging. The value returned by `Scanner.next()` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Also note that just calling `s.trim().toLowerCase();` won't do anything useful - neither of those methods *modifies* the string they're called on... they *return* a new string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your problem is the use of the next() method of the scanner. That returns the next chunk of text delimited by whitespace. So with your example input, "computer is fun ?",  next() should be returning "computer".

Try using nextLine() instead of next()

Comment: Hi GreyBeardedGeek,
Thanks for your answer, it works.